# jQuery-ui autocomplete, select first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use jQuery-ui autocomplete in my rails application. When I type some input I want it to automatically select the first item in the autocomplete box. How should I implement this?

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $('#transaction_receiver_name').autocomplete({
        source: $('#transaction_receiver_name').data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});
```

My css

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
}

ul.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  cursor: default;
  li {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: black;
    border-top: solid 1px #DDD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    a {
      color: #000;
      display: block;
      padding: 3px;
    }
    a.ui-state-hover, a.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #FFFCB2;
    }
  }
}
```

[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW5Fh.png)

Comment: Why not makeuse of the `open` callback to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `autoFocus: true` and it will automatically select the first element that shows in the list.

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $('#transaction_receiver_name').autocomplete({
        source: $('#transaction_receiver_name').data('autocomplete-source'),
        autoFocus: true
        }

    });
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //Here you can add anycode you want to be executed when an item of the box is selected
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
     //Code here will be executed when an item is clicked on 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* this will change the style of the selected element of the box*/

.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-active {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="tags">
```

Comment: Not sure that is correct: *If set to `true` the first item will automatically be focused when the menu is shown.* This will set the focus on the first item but will not select it and close the menu.

Comment: @Chiller This idea works fine for me, except for the `focus` part. 
This is because `$(this).autocomplete("close");` is closing the box before seeing anything and `$(this).val(ui.item.key);` deletes the value in the text field

Comment: @EgonMeijers do you want it to just focus on the first item of the box or you need it to do something else?

Comment: @Chiller Added a picture of the menu box and the title explains it all

Comment: @Chiller to your answer

Comment: @Chiller already found it :) http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/

Comment: @EgonMeijers i found it too :) ... what you asked requires a css code .. you can see the example in my answer

Comment: @Chiller woops I edited your jQuery part in the answer so I can only see the css it in the edit history

Answer (score 1):

When the menu opens, you could collect the first list item and use that as the value. For example:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#transaction_receiver_name').autocomplete({
    source: $('#transaction_receiver_name').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function(e, ui){
      var first = $(".ui-menu-item:eq(0) div").html();
      $(this).val(first);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This is untested.

Another  method is to trigger click on the first element.

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#transaction_receiver_name').autocomplete({
    source: $('#transaction_receiver_name').data('autocomplete-source'),
    open: function(e, ui){
      $(".ui-menu-item:eq(0)").trigger("click");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The first method will add the first item in the list immediately when typing the first letter, and if you delete the word for example halfway it will autocomplete it again. The second method doesn't show an item list. It will just add the first item in the list like the first method.

Comment: The second method works for me if the item list is already visible.